# What is the int needed for in map(int, icount) in Pydoop

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce

In the official [Pydoop tutorial](https://github.com/malli3131/HadoopTutorial/blob/master/Pydoop/Tutorial) there is a word count example.

I understand how it works, but I am wondering about the inner workings of `map(int, icounts))`.

Do I follow correctly that icounts is a list of 1s? Where does the int come from and why map?

```
# Compute the word frequency

import pydoop

def mapper(_, text, writer):
    for word in text.split():
        writer.emit(word, "1")

def reducer(word, icounts, writer):
    writer.emit(word, sum(map(int, icounts)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A type like `int` can be applied as a function to a value to convert that value to an integer (if it supports that conversion).

For example:

```
s = '1'
i = int(s)  # `i` will be `1`, where `s` is `'1'`
```

`icounts` in your example is likely an iterable (like a list) of string values, and mapping `int` over it turns that into an iterable of integer values.

Comment: Oh of course! And I see it’s sent as a String by the mapper.